# How to calculate which primes have good reduction?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I'm trying to find for which primes the elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ defined by $y^2z+yz^2=x^3-xz^2$, for example, has good reduction.

I think the way to go would be to find the minimal Weierstrass model but I have no idea about how to do it except asking PARI. Is there a simple algorithm (doable by hand) which works at least most of the time?

Comment: Tate's algorithm computes the primes of bad reduction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate%27s_algorithm

Comment: If you don't care of $2,3$ then put it in the form $y^2=x^3+ax+b$, the bad reduction primes are those such that $v_p(Disc(E))$ is not a multiple of $12$.

Comment: @reuns how can we be sure that this is the minimal Weierstrass form?

Comment: @ViktorVaughn I was looking for something plausible to do by hand

Comment: If good reduction there is an isomorphism sending the $\Bbb{F}_p$ curve to $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ and this isomorphism comes from one sending your curve to $y^2=x^3+ax+b$.

Comment: @Gabriel I just did Tate's algorithm by hand and found that $37$ is the only prime of bad reduction and has Kodaira symbol $I_1$. What exactly makes you say it's implausible to do this by hand? It took me about a page and a half of calculations.

Comment: If you really want to compute a minimal model, [Laska gave a simplified algorithm](https://doi.org/10.2307%2F2007483) to do so based on Tate's algorithm. The general algorithm looks involved, but over $\mathbb{Q}$ it is quite short. Silverman gives some sufficient criteria in *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, Ch. VII, Remark 1.1. Namely if $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and any of the following hold, the equation is minimal: (i) $v_p(\Delta) < 12$, (ii) $v_p(c_4) < 4$, or (iii) $v_p(c_6) < 6$.